# LibGdx - Installation Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I imported into Eclipse LibGdx but I have a problem with the version on android. Everything went well, creating a project and importing LibGdx to Ecipse.
I have two errors:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for android.os.Handler. Fix the build path then try building this project    test-android        Unknown    Java Problem

and:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The type android.os.Handler cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    AndroidLauncher.java    /test-android/src/com/mygdx/test/android    line 1    Java Problem

I format the disk, thinking that this will solve the problem but I still have the same errors.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it installing Eclipse ADT Plugin.

At Eclipse
 - Help -> Install New Software

- In "Work with" whrite: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- Add
- Select All
- Finish
- Agree
- Reload Eclipse
- Project -> Properties -> Android -> Choose at Project build target
- Then click OK
- Refresh android project

Wait a sec and error should be gone.